# C++ Tilde Operator on bool

Tags: c++, boolean, integer-promotion, tilde, logical-or

I've done the LinkedIn C++ Assessment and got the following question:

**What is the result from executing this code snippet?**

```
bool x=true, x=false;

if(~x || y) {
    /*part A*/
}
else {
   /*part B*/
}
```

I don't know anymore what the answers were, but I thought "B" should be displayed, right?

I thought by "~", x is inverted ("bitwise NOT") and is therefore no longer "true"

But when I run the code, I get "A":

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    bool x = true, y = false;

    std::cout << "x: " << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "~x: " << ~x << std::endl;

    if (~x || y) {
        std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
x: 1
~x: -2
A
```

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: `false` is `0` and `true` is anything else, in your case the compiler initialized x to `1`. The bitwise complement of `1` is not `0` but a value with all bits set except the last one (which as an int would be -2). Thus you still get `true`

Comment: @dave: No, `true` is not "anything else".  Conversion of `bool` to any integral type will always produce exactly `+1` for `true`.  The conversion happens here due to applying "the usual promotions" to operands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this expression

```
~x
```

there is applied the integral promotions to the operand x of the type bool. The result of the promotion is an object of the type `int` that has the value equal to 1 like (in binary)

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
```

The operator ~ inverses bits and you will get

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111110
```

From the C++ 14 Standard (5.3.1 Unary operators)

> 10 The operand of ~ shall have integral or unscoped enumeration type;
> the result is the one’s complement of its operand. Integral promotions
> are performed. The type of the result is the type of the promoted
> operand.

and (4.5 Integral promotions)

> 6 A prvalue of type bool can be converted to a prvalue of type int,
> with false becoming zero and true becoming one.
>
> 7 These conversions are called integral promotions.

As this value is not equal to 0 then used as an operand of the logical OR operator it is implicitly converted to the boolean value true.

From the C Standard (5.15 Logical OR operator)

> 1 The || operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both
> contextually converted to bool (Clause 4). It returns true if either
> of its operands is true, and false otherwise. Unlike |, || guarantees
> left-to-right evaluation; moreover, the second operand is not
> evaluated if the first operand evaluates to true.

and (4.12 Boolean conversions)

> 1 A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer
> to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type bool. A zero
> value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted
> to false; any other value is converted to true. For
> direct-initialization (8.5), a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t can be
> converted to a prvalue of type bool; the resulting value is false.